# What are the benefits/weaknesses of different diffusion models in radiation transport?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, radiation, diffusion, transport-phenomena

Can anyone summarize or point me toward references for why someone would choose one diffusion model over another, particularly in relation to radiation transport during a nuclear blast? The diffusion models I am looking for information on are:

1. Implicit Monte-Carlo
2. Gray
3. Multi-group
4. Discrete Ordinate

I am working on familiarizing myself with these approaches, but I am finding very little information on comparisons between them or what regimes each one should be used in. Any help would be greatly appreciated!